# Spring Boot Issue between jar and task that build jar: Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Right now I am having this issue where I need to have my SpringBoot application be turned into an executable jar, but it needs to be done in a task as opposed to just a configuration in the gradle.build.

So the below snippet in my `build.gradle` will produce an executable jar:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.path.name.to.main.App'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Everything works, but when I make the jar creation a task the jar no long becomes executable and throws this error **Error: Could not find or load main class `com.path.name.to.main.App`**
:

```
task makeJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = 'app.jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.path.name.to.main.App'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

The way my company does deployments it is advisable to have the jar creation in a task in the `build.gradle` as opposed to the configuration mentioned above.

However, I'm not really sure why moving it from `jar` config to a task would affect the outcome of the actual jar that was created and what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `jar` configuration you are talking about is actually a task of type `Jar`, it just gets created by Gradle (most probably by its [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)). Checkout the documentation on tasks created by plugins that are applied to your build script.

As an example you may access your task `makeJar` in the same way as the task `jar` once it has been created:

```
task makeJar(type: Jar)

makeJar {
   // configuration things
}
```

> The way my company does deployments it is advisable to have the jar creation in a task in the `build.gradle` as opposed to the configuration mentioned above.

Knowing that `jar` is also a task shows that this deployment policy of your company does not make sense at all. You can configure and use the task `jar` in the same way as a task that was created manually.

However, sometimes it makes sense to both produce a JAR file with just the project classes and an executable JAR. Since the `jar` task already produces the first one, we need another task to produce the second one. Executable JARs are also called fat oder uber JARs and there is actually a [really good plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to create them.

The root of your actual problem is that the task `jar`, since it is created by the Java plugin, has some configuration applied to it automatically that your task `makeJar` is missing. With the line `from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }` all your project dependencies inside the `compile` configuration are added to the JAR, but the code in your own project is missing. The following code adds the contents of the regular `jar` task:

```
task makeJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = 'app.jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.path.name.to.main.App'
    }
    with jar
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```